# How to switch between Advanced and simplified list of algorithim in QGIS 2.14.1?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, interface

[image]There is no option to switch between advanced Advanced and simplified  list of algorithm in this version 2.14.1 at the bottom of processing tool

Answer (score 5):

This option has been removed in QGIS 2.14 according to the [Changelog](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog214/index.html#feature-improved-toolbox):

> The simplified interface has been removed, and a new and more user-friendly system of managing providers has been added. The algorithm search functionality now also searches in providers that are not active, and suggests activating them.

---

**Edit:**

If you want to find the SAGA Grid Analysis tool - Ordered Weighted Averaging, you can type in the name of the tool in the search box.

Comment: I am trying to find out **Grid Analysis** in SAGA geo algorithm I tryied to search that in search box I m not able to find, can u suggest something

Comment: @udAyKumArVermA - What kind of [Grid Analysis](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.6/grid_analysis.html) tool are you looking for?

Comment: see i m trying do to according to the tutorial i have given screen shot of that in the question

Comment: @udAyKumArVermA - Did you try typing in "ordered" in the seach box?

Comment: @udAyKumArVermA - Most welcome, glad you found it ;)